# Reading from a pipe even after the write end is closed

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pipe, fork

Can you please explain me why is the child process able to read even after the parent closes its write end?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int fd[2];
    char buffer[20];

    pipe(fd);

    if ( fork() ==  0 ) //child
    {
        close(fd[0]); //As it is writing close the read end
        strcpy(buffer, "Hello World");
        write(fd[1], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        close(fd[1]);
    }
    else            //parent
    {
        close(fd[1]);   //As it is reading closing the write end
        while(1)
        {
                read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                printf("Buffer:%s\n", buffer);
                sleep(1);
        }
        close(fd[0]);
    }
}
```

O/P: Child continuously prints:

```
Buffer:Hello World
```

Why is the child able to receive even when the parent terminates? Shouldn't `read` get `EOF`?

Comment: It doesn't.  The subsequent reads fail, but you're ignoring that, and the content of the buffer doesn't change, so you see the same information over and over...

Comment: ... why do you think it should terminate?

Comment: After reading the return value, it is "0" from second time. Does it mean EOF

Comment: Yes, that's how you detect EOF when using `read()`.

Comment: Have you bothered to read the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) of the function to see how it works? **If the current file offset is at or past the end of file, no bytes are read, and `read()` returns zero.**

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the child able to receive even when the parent terminates? Shouldn't `read` get `EOF`?

At that point the parent process is basically reading nothing (i.e.: `read()` is returning `0`) and printing over and over what it had read in a previous call to `read()`.

---

You have to look at the value returned by the `read()` system call. That value is of type `int`, and basically :

- `-1`: error, something went wrong.
- `0`: nothing else remaining to read, i.e.: **`EOF`** (what you were looking for).
- Otherwise: the *number of bytes read* by `read()` that were stored into `buffer`.

You can rewrite the parent's `while`-loop accordingly:

```
while(1) {
    int count = read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    switch (count) {
    case 0: // EOF
        break;
    case -1: // read() error
        // ... error handling ...
        break;
    default: // fine
        // count contains the number of bytes read
        buffer[count] = '\0'; // NUL character, to indicate the end of string
        printf("Buffer:%s\n", buffer);
        sleep(1);  
    }
}
```